# how to Append a relative formula into a sheet using the google sheet api

Tags: android, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-formula

I am appending a row to a google sheet using the api and it works fine but the last object in the row is a formula. instead of changing to reflect the row it is on like =E3-D3, =E4-D4, it stays static and always puts =E3-D3 in the row. The formula works for that row only.

This is for android and I am using the Java library.  I know there must be an easy way to do this, its so common but I am missing it.
here is a code sample:

these are the objects I am passing in: o6 is the formula and it is wrong, but I am not sure how to fix.

```
 Object o1 = result.getDate(), o2 = result.getDescription(), o3 =  
 String.valueOf(result.getDistance()), o4 = result.getStartTime(),o5 = 
 result.getEndTime(), **o6 ="=E3-D3";**





//for the values that you want to input, create a list of object lists
    List<List<Object>> values = new ArrayList<>();


    //values.add(data1);

    //todo me
    values.add(data);

    //Create the valuerange object and set its fields


    ValueRange valueRange = new ValueRange();
    valueRange.setMajorDimension("ROWS");
    valueRange.setRange(range);
    valueRange.setValues(values);

    AppendValuesResponse avResponse = null;

    try {
        avResponse = this.mService.spreadsheets().values()
                .append(mSpreadSheetId, range, valueRange)
                .setValueInputOption("USER_ENTERED")
                .execute();
```

Up until now all the formulas I have used occupied a single cell and summed a whole column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use relative formulae instead of absolute formulae with R1C1 notation.

> There are two positioning notations used in Google Sheets. The first, called A1 notation, uses characters from the Latin alphabet to indicate the column, and integers to indicate the row of a cell. The second, called R1C1 notation, uses integers to represent both the column and the row, and precedes each by a corresponding R or C, to indicate row or column number. The addresses A1 and R1C1 are equivalent, as are the addresses B5 and R5C2.

So for example, if the cell you want to update is in column H, but you want it to always reflect the row even if the column is different, use relative notation to do this. The [INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en) formula keyword can help you here:

```
=E3-D3
```

becomes:

```
=INDIRECT("R[0]C[-3]", FALSE)-INDIRECT("R[0]C[-4]",FALSE)
```

For column H.

Comment: Not sure what you men by H; I need for whatever the current row is I am appending the columns would always be E & D.

Comment: I was using H as an exmaple - in the R1C1 notation the R stands for relative Row and C stands for relative Column. E is 3 columns left of H and D is 4 columns left of H so for this case you would use `R[0]C[-3]` and `R[0]C[-4]`. It depends in which column you're adding the line.

Comment: so for the string given the  formula is: 
    =INDIRECT("R[0]C[-1]", FALSE)- 
      INDIRECT("R[0]C[-2]",FALSE)    thanks!!

Comment: If the cell you want to update is in column F, yes.